# Toilet noise after a flush

Tags: plumbing, toilet

After a flush, it whines and makes high pitched noises when filling tank up. Time for new stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, time for new stuff.

If you have a more specific question then i would be happy to try and answer it.

Your question should include all relevant info on the type of stuff you have and your experience in working with stuff.

**Be as detailed as possible**.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it may be rust scale or gravel in the valve , flushing the valve may fix it. Turn the supply off open the top of the fill valve some twist some have tabs. Remove the top put a glass or jar over the top and turn the water on, some tiles it is amazing how much grit comes out, turn the valve off reassemble and see if this fixed the problem it has worked for me many times.